# How to set focus for element on page load?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am new to AngularDart and I want to focus the first input on page (with my attribute from decorator) but I can't figure out how to do this. This is my decorator:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Decorator(selector: '[autofocus]')
class InputFocus implements AttachAware {
    final html.InputElement element;

    InputFocus(html.Element this.element) {
        element.onFocus.listen((_) => print('element focused'));
    }

    @Override
    attach() {
        element.focus();
    }
}
```

When I click on the element the message is printed so the element is the on I am looking for. Somehow the element isn't focused on attach cause the message isn't printed when I reload the page. How can I achieve my goal? Maybe there is another approach to reach the element when the DOM is rendered?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some delay should help

```
new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () => element.focus());
```

Comment: This actually works for selecting input with InputElement.select(). Somehow putting this on the end of event queue seems to be just right even though the approach seems weird. The Duration needs to be just 0 or negative number cause we just need to put on the end of the event queue. +1

Comment: This helped me a lot. Just to point out a small typo, a parenthesis is missing after 50.